# Invalid syntax from ypolk -l

Tags: django

I having a lot of trouble to install and config Django and Postgres so I can use them in eclipse.

I try to follow the instructions from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1STjuSTKcU&feature=youtu.be)
but when I typed

```
ypolk -l
```

i got:

```
 C:\Users\yaira\Documents\YASMIN\virtual_enviroments>yolk -l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yaira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\yolk-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('yolk==0.4.3', 'console_scripts', 'yolk')()
  File "c:\users\yaira\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\yaira\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\yaira\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\yaira\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "c:\users\yaira\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\yolk\cli.py", line 262
    print " %s %s (%s)" % (project_name, dist.version,
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea what does it mean, and what to do do with those results.

Comment: Note: I assume you meant `yolk` instead of `ypolk` which your site packages would suggest, you wouldn't get very far by typing `ypolk`

Answer (score 0):

It would appear as though `yolk` does not support Python 3 too well according to [this bug report](https://github.com/cakebread/yolk/issues/30).

Their suggested solution is to try using [yolk3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk3k/) and uninstall `yolk`

> Make sure you uninstall yolk before installing yolk3k so you can use the "yolk" commands in yolk3k